# How to validate Automapper mappings but only in the direction Dto to Entity

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, automapper, .net-6.0

I am using Automapper to map my DTO's to Entities but not viceversa.
So I want to validate those mappings but only from the side of DTO's not the way around.
Ie.

```
public class UserDto
{
     public string FirstName {get;set;}
     public string Lastname {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
public class User
{
     public string Username {get;set;}
     public string FirstName {get;set;}
     public string LastName {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

in this example the validation should tell me that there is no Lastname property on the User class because User has LastName property. But it should NOT tell me that there is no Username property on the UserDto- because I dont need it. I want the validation to be from UserDto to User, and not User to UserDto.

How to do that?

Comment: What does your mapping configuration look like right now? Should be something like:
`profile.CreateMap<UserDto, User>();` Also, are you using FluentValidation?

Comment: I have a class that inherits from Profile, and in it I have CreateMap<UserDto, User>();..
I don't have FluentValidation.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#selecting-members-to-validate

Comment: Yes, I can use this also, but then I need to have two configurations as I understand, One for mapping and other for validation and need to keep them in sync?

Comment: No. You just specify per map what you want to validate. The default seems just fine in your case.

Comment: Ok, Will try it.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution that works for me:

```
public void AssertAllSourcePropertiesMapped()
    {
        var listOfErrors = new List<string>();

        var maps = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps();
        foreach (var map in maps.Where(x=>x.SourceType.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("dto")))
        {
            var destinationProperties = map.DestinationType.GetProperties().ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, x=>x);
            foreach (var propertyMap in map.PropertyMaps.Where(x=>x.Ignored == false))
            {
                var sourcePropertyName = propertyMap.SourceMember.Name;
                var sourcePropertyType = propertyMap.SourceMember.GetMemberType();
                var destinationPropertyName = propertyMap.DestinationMember.Name;
                var destinationPropertyType = propertyMap.DestinationMember.GetMemberType();
                var destinationType = propertyMap.DestinationMember.ReflectedType;

                if (destinationProperties.TryGetValue(destinationPropertyName, out var property))
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType != sourcePropertyType)
                    {
                        listOfErrors.Add(
                            $"Property: {propertyMap.SourceMember.ReflectedType.Name}.{sourcePropertyName} of Type: {sourcePropertyType} does not match destination type: {destinationType} property Type of: {property.PropertyType.Name}");
                    }
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    listOfErrors.Add(
                        $"Property: {propertyMap.SourceMember.ReflectedType.Name}.{sourcePropertyName} of Type: {sourcePropertyType} has not been found on Type: {destinationType}");
                }
            }                
        
        }

        if (listOfErrors.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfErrors));
        }
    }
```